# How to enable a disabled textfield, based on some condition in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs

I tried using this code

```
listeners : {
  afterrender : function(comp) {
    var countryValue = data.countryCode;
    if (countryValue == "AU" && Ext.isEmpty(comp.getValue())) {
        Ext.getCmp('state').markInvalid('When Country is AU, State is mandatory.');
        Ext.getCmp('state').enable();
        comp.inputValue = true;
    } else {
        comp.clearInvalid();
    }
  }
}
```

State field is disabled initially. Only when the country field gets value as "AU", the state field needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of enable(), you need to give setdisabled(false);

```
listeners : {
afterrender : function(comp) {
var countryValue = data.countryCode;
if(countryValue == "AU" && Ext.isEmpty(comp.getValue())){
    Ext.getCmp('state').markInvalid('When Country is AU, State is mandatory.');
    Ext.getCmp('state').setdisabled(false);
    comp.inputValue = true;
}else{
    comp.clearInvalid();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you see the  [Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.form.field.Text.html) of textfield enable method is changeable and 'Passing true will suppress the enable event from being fired'. We can not enable it by just passing `enable()`because its need Boolean value to make it operative.  Therefore your line `Ext.getCmp('state').enable();` is not working.

Yes you have `setDisabled(false)` which can make the value enable.

Your line will be

```
Ext.getCmp('state').setDisabled(false);
```

Comment: You have a typo in the method name, it must be `setDiasbled`.